# PDO MySQL query using apostrophes in LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, pdo, sql-like, in-operator

I have following query

```php
$area = "AREA V";

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT areas FROM ranks WHERE areas LIKE :area");
$sql->bindValue(':area', '%' . $area . '%');
$sql->execute();
$num = $sql->rowCount();
```

Column `area` contains data e.g. `'AREA I', 'AREA V', 'AREA VII'`.

The problem is that when I'm executing query with `LIKE '%AREA V%'` there are results without `AREA V` but with `AREA VI` and `AREA VII`. That's right, and so it should, but I don't want that.

I have tried to put apostrophes in `LIKE` clause, but I don't get it to work.

**Things that I've tried:**

```php
// using apostrophes and PDO::PARAM_STR
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT areas FROM ranks WHERE areas LIKE :area");
$sql->bindValue(':area', '%'' . $area . ''%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

// using IN
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT areas FROM ranks WHERE :area IN (areas)");
$sql->bindValue(':area', $area);
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you get the missing values, when you change the search value to **%AREA%**, possibly after adjusting the `WHERE` into `UPPER(areas) like :area`? Did you try `SELECT DISTINCT areas FROM ranks ORDER BY areas` with any success?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are searching for `'Area V'` *with* the single quotes.  I think you just need to delimit the strings correctly.  Something like:

```
// using apostrophes and PDO::PARAM_STR
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT areas FROM ranks WHERE areas LIKE :area");
$sql->bindValue(':area', "%'" . $area . "'%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The value you want is represented in SQL as `'%''Area V'''`.  Double single quotes are used to put single quotes in a string.